# Get the number of highest ID number column

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have data like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID_0=c("25","25"),
ID_1=c("1","2"),
ID_2=c("a","b")
)

df2 <- data.frame(ID_0=c("25","25"),
ID_1=c("1","2"),
ID_2=c("a","b"),
ID_3=c("c","d"),
ID_4=c("3","4")
)

df3 <- data.frame(ID_0=c("25","25")
)
```

I'd like a function like this(made up example, doesn't actually work):

```
which.max.ID(df1)
[1] 2

which.max.ID(df2)
[1] 4

which.max.ID(df3)
[1] 0
```

Comment: There are also letters in some IDs.

Comment: Intentionally so, in the real dataset they could possibly be either numeric or character

Comment: Thank you akrun, but should it matter? I'm just trying to pull the max number out of the ID colnames

Comment: Do you mean out of the column names? e.g., `max(as.numeric(sub("ID_", "", names(df2), fixed = TRUE)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `gsub` to remove all the non-numeric elements, convert to `numeric` and get the `max`

```
fmax <- function(dat){
     nm1 <- grep("ID", names(dat), value = TRUE)
     stopifnot(length(nm1) > 0)
     max(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", nm1)))
  }

fmax(df1)
#[1] 2
fmax(df2)
#[1] 4
fmax(df3)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks akrun.